# sed : match all instances of regex in infile1.txt, and output only these to outfile2.txt

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have a text file infile1 with 1,000's of lines.

I wish to use sed to extract the occuring instances of a regex pattern match to outfile2.

NB 
Each instance of the regex pattern match may occur more than once on each line of infile1.
Each instance of the extracted regex pattern should be printed to a new line in outfile2.

Does anyone know the syntax within sed to place the regex into?

ps the regex pattern is

```
\(Google[ ]{1,3}“[a-zA-Z0-9 ]{1,100}[., ]{0,3}”\)
```

Thank you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want

```
grep -oE 'Google[ ]{1,3}"[a-zA-Z0-9 ]{1,100}[., ]{0,3}"' filename
```

`-o` tells `grep` to print only the matches, each on a line of its own, and `-E` instructs it to interpret the regex in extended POSIX syntax, which your regex appears to be.

Note that `[ ]` could be replaced with just a space, and you might want to use `[[:alnum:] ]` instead of `[a-zA-Z0-9 ]` to cover umlauts and suchlike if they exist in the current locale.

**Addendum:** It is also possible to do this with sed. I don't recommend it, but you could write (using GNU sed):

```
sed -rn 's/Google[ ]{1,3}"[A-Za-z0-9 ]{1,100}[., ]{0,3}"/\n&\n/g; s/[^\n]*\n([^\n]*\n)/\1/g; s/\n[^\n]*$//p' filename
```

To make this work with older versions of BSD sed, use `-En` instead of `-rn`. `-r` and `-E` enable extended regex syntax. `-r` was historically used by GNU sed, `-E` by BSD sed; newer versions of them support both for compatibility. `-n` disables auto-printing.

The code works as follows:

```
# mark all occurrences of the regex by circumscribing them with newlines
s/Google[ ]{1,3}"[A-Za-z0-9 ]{1,100}[., ]{0,3}"/\n&\n/g

# Isolate every other line from the pattern space (the matches). This will
# leave the part behind the last match...
s/[^\n]*\n([^\n]*\n)/\1/g

# ...so we remove it afterwards and print the result of the transformation if it
# happened (the s///p flag does that). The transformation will not happen if
# there were no matches in the line (because then no newlines will have been
# inserted), so in those cases nothing will be printed.
s/\n[^\n]*$//p
```

Comment: Thank you :) @Wintermute. `E` did not work on my system and produced a `'grep: Invalid range end'` error. When I changed this to `P` it worked a treat. I added >> outfile and thats it. It works perfectly. Here is what I used : `grep -oP 'Google[ ]{1,3}“[a-zA-z0-9 ]{1,100}[., ]{0,3}”' infile.txt >> outfile.txt`

Comment: Oh, a typo snuck in there (`A-z` instead of `A-Z`, with a lower-case `z`). I fixed it in the answer. `-P` means to use Perl regexes, which is also fine, but you'll need to fix the interval in a Perl regex just the same.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with `sed` too, but it isn't pretty:

```
sed -n ':start /foo/{ h; s/\(foo\).*/\1/; s/.*\(foo\)/\1/; p; g; s/foo\(.*\)/\1/; b start; }' infile1 >outfile2
```

-- provided that you replace the four occurences of `foo` above with your pattern `Google {1,3}“[a-zA-Z0-9 ]{1,100}[., ]{0,3}”`.

Yeah, I told you it isn't pretty. :)

Comment: Thankfully, there are easier ways to do this particular thing with sed. I added one to my answer, in case you're interested. FWIW, I can see how you'd arrive at this solution; more complex sed scripts can at times turn out something like it. When they do, I tend to take it as a sign that it's time to switch to other tools (such as perl).